# Correctly forming API response

Tags: php, api, symfony, foreach

I am building a simple API response for my app with Symfony. This is the response I am trying to achieve:

```
   "academy_programs": {
     "academy_program": {
        “program_name”: “MySQL”,
        “program_price”: 100,
    }
     "academy_program": {
        “program_name”: “PHP,
        “program_price”: 500,
    }
  }
```

So far, my response looks like this:

```
    "academy_programs": {
        "program_name": [
            "MySQL",
            "PHP"
        ],
        "program_price": [
            100,
            500
        ]
    }
```

Here is the code I wrote.

```
$programsArray = array();
$priceArray = array();

foreach ($academy->getPrograms() as $program) {
  $programsArray[] = $program->getProgramName();
}

foreach ($academy->getPrograms() as $price) {
  $priceArray[] = $price->getProgramPrice();
}

$programs = new \stdClass();
$programs->program_name = $programsArray;
$programs->program_price = $priceArray;
```

I am missing another `foreach` that would loop through each entry.

Comment: just parse your array using `json_encode()` and it will create josn response

Comment: But will it create an individual entry like I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the results in 2 different arrays. To achieve your results, you will have to add the name and the price inside a single array as shown below:

```
<?php

$programsArray = [];
$programsArray['academy_programs'] = [];

foreach ($academy->getPrograms() as $program) {
  $programsArray['academy_programs'][] = [
    'academy_program' => [
        'program_name' => $program->getProgramName(),
        'program_price' => $program->getProgramPrice()
      ]
  ];
}


print_r($programsArray);
echo json_encode($programsArray); // json representation
```

**Update:**

As **@Jaquarh** mentioned in the comments, you can make use of [__toString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) magic method to print contents `$academy` object whenever you print the object or use it in any string context.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php


class Academy{
  /*
    other code
  */

    public function __toString(){
      $programsArray = [];
      $programsArray['academy_programs'] = [];

      foreach ($this->getPrograms() as $program) {
        $programsArray['academy_programs'][] = [
          'academy_program' => [
            'program_name' => $program->getProgramName(),
            'program_price' => $program->getProgramPrice()
          ]
        ];
      }


      return json_encode($programsArray); // json representation
    }
}


$academy = new Academy();
/*
all the other jazz
*/

echo $academy; // this would invoke the __toString() method and will give you the json representation as output.
```

Comment: Could use the `__toString` magic method to convert your Object to JSON format, then it would be as easy as `echo $academy` to get your JSON format. Simply add this into your `Academy` class as a `public function __toString()` and use `$this->getPrograms()` instead.

Comment: @Jaquarh Nice input! Updated my answer :)

Comment: @dotty I have updated my answer. This could make it even more simpler to get a JSON representation whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to create array like below and use `json_encode` as below

```
$academy_programs = [

    $academy_program = [ 'program_name' => 'MySQL', 'program_price' => '100' ],
    $academy_program = [ 'program_name' => 'PHP', 'program_price' => '500' ]
];

// echo "<pre>"; print_r($academy_programs);

echo json_encode( [ 'academy_programs' => $academy_programs ]);
```

Here you will get output as

```
{"academy_programs":[{"program_name":"MySQL","program_price":"100"},{"program_name":"PHP","program_price":"500"}]}
```

Comment: You will have to loop because `$academy->getPrograms()` could have more than 2 pieces of data.

Comment: @vivek_23 i just gave sample example with static data.